# Drools Database

Tags: java, database, drools, rule-engine

I am developing a rating system based on Drool Rules to replace a old one made with ASP and a relational DB.
Everything is running very good as expected, but  some rules become very extensive because the rating system needs to compare a lot of constant values with the input - I do not want to back to the solution of using an external database.
A this moment, there is some standard data structure that should be use to persist lot of constant values? I know it is possible to construct a Java structure for that ... but my objective is to give the rules file to the sales team, who barely understand Java but they are very good with ratios.

For example, I want to replace this with something more clean:

```
if("A".equals($inpt)) { $outpt = 0.1; }
else if("B".equals($inpt)) { $outpt = 0.2; }
else if("C".equals($inpt)) { $outpt = 0.3; }
```

Comment: Looks like a job for a `Map<String, Double>`.

Comment: You haven't provided enough context information. Where should this be available? LHS? RHS?

Comment: It should be available at RHS. Map<String, Double> will do fine, but I would use something more sophisticated if it is possible. At this moment I am thinking in build my own Java structure and apply a DSL to make it easy to understand!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll have to guess a little. Let's say you have

```
rule "set output"
when
    $s: Something(  $input: input )
    InToOut( input == $input, $output: output )
then
    modify( $s ){ setOutput( $output ) }
end
```

Your sales team members will surely understand if you give them the skeleton

```
rule "setInToOut"
salience 999999999
when
then
    insert( new InToOut( "A", 0.1 ) );
    insert( new InToOut( "B", 0.2 ) );
     ...
end
```

You can simplify this with a function.

Comment: You are right, my question context is weak, sorry!
I already have a big function with thousands of IF ELSE to replace a sql query to find some ratios between parameters. My question is intended to understand if Drools can support some kind database/dataset manipulation without using external structures or containers.